# On instance hierarchies in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, class-hierarchy

I have the following definitions:

```
data Egg = ChickenEgg | ChocolateEgg
  deriving Show
  
data Milk = Milk Int -- amount in litres
  deriving Show
  
class Price a where
  price :: a -> Int

instance Price Egg where
  price ChickenEgg = 20
  price ChocolateEgg = 30

instance Price Milk where
  price (Milk v) = 15 * v
```

The above compiles and runs OK. However, I need to be able to do something like that:

```
price (Just ChickenEgg) -- 20
price [Milk 1, Milk 2] -- 45
price [Just ChocolateEgg, Nothing, Just ChickenEgg] -- 50
price [Nothing, Nothing, Just (Milk 1), Just (Milk 2)]  -- 45
```

My best attempt for `price (Just ChickenEgg)` was:

```
instance Price (Maybe Egg) where
  price Nothing = 0
  price (Just ChickenEgg) = 20
  price (Just ChocolateEgg) = 30
```

Q: What am I doing wrong here? `:/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is really what you want to do, you can write an instance like this:

```
instance Price a => Price (Maybe a) where
  price Nothing = 0
  price (Just x) = price x
```

This enables not only `price (Just ChickenEgg)`, but getting the price of any `Maybe Price` instance:

```
ghci> price (Just ChickenEgg)
20
ghci> price (Just (Milk 2))
30
```

This, however, doesn't feel quite like idiomatic Haskell to me. There are certainly use cases where something like this is useful (e.g. [QuickCheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck) does this a lot), but often it's safer to keep the `Maybe` or list structure intact, and instead rely on built-in combinators:

```
ghci> price <$> Just ChickenEgg
Just 20
```

You can do the same with your other examples, without adding more type class instances:

```
ghci> sum $ price <$> [Milk 1, Milk 2]
45
ghci> sum $ mapMaybe (fmap price) [Just ChocolateEgg, Nothing, Just ChickenEgg]
50
ghci> sum $ mapMaybe (fmap price) [Nothing, Nothing, Just (Milk 1), Just (Milk 2)]
45
```

Comment: Thanks! That does it. BTW, I am just a Haskell beginner, so I can't write idiomatic Haskell yet.

Comment: Second opinion here -- I think this is very idiomatic.  Uniform treatment of types *and* structures built from those types is a major use-case for type classes.  See `Show` and `Eq` and their instances for `Maybe` and `[]` for some prominent examples.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr I wasn't sure how to word that little warning without digressing too much. With the mention of QucikCheck, I hoped to demonstrate that I was aware of valid use cases. In the specific case of calculating a price, too, it's probably not much of a stretch to set a missing price to 0. As a general principle, though, associating a specific value with `Nothing` can cause problems because it makes it harder to distinguish between a real price of 0 and a missing value.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Even with an innocuous-looking example like the OP `Price`, what happens if you define `Price` instances for `Maybe` and `[]`? One effect of that is that a programmer may naively calculate the average price of the above `[Nothing, Nothing, Just (Milk 1), Just (Milk 2)]` list to `11.25`, whereas I would guess that usually, `22.5` would be the correct answer.